# Should we use @Component on @Entity class in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Well i am a newbie in spring boot. I was working on a project where I needed to @Autowired my Entity in a controller class. But I ended up with error:

> Field repository in abc required a bean of type 'xyz' that could not be found.

But it solved after adding @Component in Entity class.

So my questions are:

1. Why Spring boot was not scanning my Entity class as it was under @SpringBootApplication declaration?
2. When and where we should use @Component annotation in our application?

Comment: Autowiring an entity points to a problem in the software design. The entity should come from your data store, not be managed by the Spring Framework. Can you elaborate a bit more on that use case? And maybe also show your code?

Answer (score 7):

Use @Component to flag your Pojo as Spring Bean, so that you inject it into other beans with @Autowired

Use @Entity to flag your Pojo as JPA or Spring Data managed bean to read or write it to a database